# syntaxhighlighter in blogger interpreting <br /> literally despite html encoding

Tags: blogger

I am using syntaxhighlighter on a blogger blog. All is working fine, except when the code I want to show contains a <br/> tag, it gets displayed as a new line. This is despite it being HTML encoded (and the following visible in the view source):

```
&lt;br/&gt;
```

Is this a bug in syntaxhighlighter? Or is there anything else I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked it out. It was actually turning on syntaxhighlighter's "blogger mode" that caused the problem. Turning it off works just fine.

See line 908 in http://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/src/tip/scripts/shCore.js

Answer (score 3):

See [Blogger Mode](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/BloggerMode).

> Blogger Mode
> Blogger has a nasty habit of replacing all new lines with <br/> tags which makes it impossible to post code snippets.
>
> To fix the situation version 1.5.1 introduces "Blogger Mode" which can be enabled before a call to `HighlightAll()` by a call to `BloggerMode()` like in the example below:
>
>     `dp.SyntaxHighlighter.BloggerMode();
>     dp.SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll('code');`

Comment: it was blogger mode that was the problem. I needed to turn it off